# How to make hugo server use custom 404.html

Tags: http-status-code-404, hugo

doc page https://gohugo.io/templates/404/#automatic-loading
says

*hugo server will not **automatically** load your custom 404.html file, but you can test the appearance of your custom “not found” page by navigating your browser to /404.html.*

**QUESTION:**
is there a way to explicitly configure hugo server use custom 404 page?

Comment: Not while using `hugo server` command. What is it you want to achieve by doing this? `hugo server` should only be used for development purposes.

Comment: @josephting I am kinda lazy and do not want to add nginx to my setup. I do not need any nginx features yet and serving small amount of content directly from memory like hugo server does seems to be better option.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to do this at the moment. Things might change when hugo implements REST API. https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Hugo will only produce a static website. You must use a web server in production **NOT** Hugo's development server.

Hugo should never implement an API of any kind. That's not what it was built for. I have used Hugo for a long time and have never needed such features from Hugo.

If you're able to run `hugo serve` on a server then you're likely also able to install packages. You should use nginx, or apache, or w/e you feel most comfortable with that's built for production.

Lots of tutorials online:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04

It really isn't that difficult and it will save you many headaches in the long run. If you need something to quickly show your site to others (*as this is often the case when wanting to use hugo's development server on a public facing machine*) try https://ngrok.com/